# nib but didn't get a UITableView using PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to add a search feature to my app but the screen needs to have a navigation bar in addition the search bar on the UITableView. I am getting the following error when i perform the segue (click a button) and the view loads

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "2Gx-ec-tTH-view-HBf-bD-79u" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
```

Here is what it looks like on my storyboard. [image: Screenshot of storyboard]

I believe the problem is that this scene is managed by a class called "AllDataViewController" and it manages the UIView and is a subclass of UITableView it is actually PFQueryTableViewController

```
//AllDataTableViewController.h
@interface AllDataTableViewController : PFQueryTableViewController <UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDelegate>
```

So I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. But let me know if you have any suggestions or if I need to add any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your view controller subclasses `UITableViewController` (well, indirectly via `PFQueryTableViewController`), it expects its `view` property to refer to an instance of a `UITableView`.  If you look at the object hierarchy in the storyboard scene I think you will find that the root of the scene is not a `UITableView`, but a `UIView`.

How did you add the navigation bar?  The correct method is to select "embed in..." from the Editor menu in Image Builder.

Comment: I just dragged it in from the UI. I will "embed in" and see what happens.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have the same problem. I have a `UIView` like root, can you provide a solution? Remove the `UIView` is the right way?